# 404/CAPTCHA/Error images

Tags: discussion, design

I knew I forgot something right before the new design launch today. I didn't get a chance to create custom images for the 404/Captcha/error pages on the TeX site.

Do you have any suggestions?

A few examples from other sites:

Cooking site's 404:

[image]

Gaming site's CAPTCHA

[image]

Photography site's 404 (Normally for Captcha, we do a "robot" theme.)

[image]

The idea is to have these images somewhat light hearted, and reflect the theme of the site. What are your suggestions for this site?

Comment: This question now exists as a competition on the parent site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/competition-time-design-an-error-page.

Answer (score 19):

For a 404, there could be a play on some of most common TeX error messages. I think the **Undefined control sequence** is most appropriate.

As for an image, something simple like this:

```
\404{Page not found}

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \404
```

Or some variation thereof.

Probably rendered in different styles, to distinguish user input from TeX complaints.

Comment: But the standard catcodes of 4 and 0 won't allow that to happen. I think `\cdiv` would be more more in the spirit of TeX. On the other hand, how many would recognize what it stands for? Perhaps it would be a great inside joke. Oh, what the heck; I'll enter it as an answer so people can vote on it.

Answer (score 12):

Badness 10000!!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

We don't know how you arrived in room 404, but we have been working for a long  time to correct all bugs!

Comment: I think this type of old book illustrations work really well! Here's a good site where all the images are in public domain: http://www.oldbookillustrations.com/

Comment: @Jin Thanks - and I love the new design!

Answer (score 8):

Use one of Don Knuth's [Road Signs](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/diamondsigns/diam.html) or the [Dangerous Bend Sign](http://www.truetex.com/db.htm)

[image: Dangerous Bend]

Comment: Actually that sign was introduced by Bourbaki (though that shouldn't stop us from using it).

Comment: Ahh yes... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol

Comment: Yeah, but Bourbaki didn't code it up in METAFONT ;-P

Answer (score 5):

What's with something like this:

```
*\show\page
> \page=undefined.
```

Maybe in combination with an assign tracing:

```
{changing \error=0}
{into \error=404}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is this variant on Martin Tapankov's answer:

```
\cdiv{Page not found}

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \cdiv
```

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) if this mystifies you.

Comment: Ha ha.  I had to look at the URL (but not click through).