# The 404 not found image is not unique

Tags: discussion

This site's `404 not found` image is not unique. It's shared with Cross Validated.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/404
https://stats.stackexchange.com/404

It's entirely possible that this is intentional, but since most sites don't have the same image, I thought it was reasonable to suspect that it was a bug.

Sister bug report:
[on Meta Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)

Comment: Interestingly creating a CrossValidated account (to tell them that this isn't a bug) gave me 100 free rep on the TeX site (saying that I associated my Area 51 account).

Comment: not all sites' 404/captcha/error images are unique, although I'd like them to be. I re-use those that I think are appropriate. For now, I think the Stats ones work OK with the Tex site. Also see @Stefan's answer below.

Comment: @Caramdir, yeah, the associations can be a bit wonky, there's been discussion on MSO about that.

Comment: @Jin, okay, I didn't know if it was by design. I saw one dupe, and thought it might just have been an oversight, but then I found more....

Answer (score 5):

The 404 image is not yet decided and designed, have a look at [404/CAPTCHA/Error images](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/404-captcha-error-images).