# Still missing illustrations from Duane Bibby

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There was a [post by Jin](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/404-captcha-error-images) asking what we should do for the captcha/404/etc. images.

This was followed up by a [post to main](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/competition-time-design-an-error-page), in which we seem to mostly agreed that it would be really cool if we could get some illustrations done by Daune Bibby, who illustrated the TeXbook and made [this cool illustration](http://www.ctan.org/lion.html) for CTAN, among other things:

[image: "CTAN Lion"]

Now, someone just needs to make it **happen**!

Answer (score 12):

I have updated the CAPTCHA image to the lion pic. It will be on live with the next deployment. I wasn't sure if we have the rights to use the image legally. But then  I read on http://www.ctan.org/lion.html as long as we provide attribution, then it was OK.

FYI here's how the CAPTCHA image looks like:

[image]

Comment: I own the drawing.  You- or anyone- can use it any way that you like; the request for attribution is a request only.

Comment: @Jim thank you!

Comment: If the status of this question is completed, why haven't moderators assigned it with a red "status-completed" tag yet?

Answer (score 7):

Duane works on a commission basis. AFAIK we don't have a budget, so this would be pretty much out of the question unless we go looking for sponsorship.

Comment: That's pretty much what I expected; is there any reason we shouldn't do that?

Comment: In the last ConTeXt user meeting, a [drawing](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/talks/2010-09-17-closing/wolfgang-color.jpg) by Bibby was presented to one of the users. I don't know the details, but someone could ask the [meeting organizers](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/).

Comment: Very often Hans himself pays, sometimes it goes from meeting's budget and sometimes one of the user groups pays. One should either ask if sx is willing to pay and if not, ask DANTE, TUG or start raising the money from SX users. (I have ConTeXt meeting 2011 painting above my desk as well. I was sooooo happy about the present :) But SX does fund a few things (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/). The problem is probably that paying for a nice 404 page won't attract more traffic to the site.