# Is error message a joke or typo?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Says opps instead of oops.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/error

not saying I don't think it is kinda funny, I was just looking at all the stackexchange error messages for some breaktime amusement and noticed it.

Comment: It's also inconsistently capitalised: either upper case the initial "b", or lower case the initial "h".

Comment: IMHO it is a typo.

Comment: ... and in the text above the picture everything is OK.

Answer (score 3):

"OPPS." It's a typo. Also It was meant to be a temporarily place holder image.

Now may be a good opportunity to ask, is it OK if I create the official 404 image from the highest voted answer on the [404 image post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/404-captcha-error-images/662#662)? If so, what type setting etc should I use? It'd be great if one of you can show me exactly how it should be presented, so I don't come up with something not authentic.

Thanks!

Comment: hmmmm. I think that 9 votes does not a selection indicate.

Comment: @Yossi, I'm definitely open for suggestions. Feel free to post new ideas in the 404 image thread.

Comment: @Jin: Don't forget the competition on the parent site: [Competition time: Design an error page!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/competition-time-design-an-error-page) You may also want to have a look at [Aditya's comment here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/865/still-missing-illustrations-from-duane-bibby/868#868).

Comment: @Jin: I am not saying I have a better idea...but the problem is that there are no temporary solutions....it's very difficult to rally the community to change a temporary one...better to wait (I think) until a good solution arrives (like the issue with choosing a domain).

Comment: @Yossi sure, understandable. Meanwhile I can correct the typo, and maybe put in a new temporary one. (since the current one out there doesn't really fit the overall design theme of the site).

Comment: @Jin: Community just bumped this. Can you please fix the typos?

Comment: @hendrik I fixed the typo, will be in the next deployment.