# What kinds of non-author edits are welcome here?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it (and isn't) acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit)

Quite often non-CW questions and answers are edited and corrected by users who didn't write the original text. The edits range from small fixes to, in some cases, additions that complement or change the meaning of the original question or answer — without author's consent. It is clear that there should be a limit of how much the post can be edited by others.

Therefore the question is as follows: what kinds of post edits can be freely done? What edits, on the other hand, should be only suggested to the author in a comment?

For a start, let's list a few common cases in which the post can be edited:

- Changing question tags
- Noticeably improving formatting and correcting many grammar mistakes at once
- Removing salutation and signature from the text

Comment: More or less a duplicate of this question: [When is it (and isn't) acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/340/2693)

Comment: @Alan: Ohh, I missed that. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "How do we make new editors aware of what are acceptable edits?"

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit