# Dealing with anonymous edits

Tags: discussion, editing

Friends, I stumbled upon an anonymous edit suggestion yesterday in the review system which was actually good, but I went for `not sure`. I decided to **not** accept it because there was no user info, although the contribution was valid.

IMHO I think that editing things from other users [is a risky contract](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2614/3094), so my suggestion is to consider edits made by registered people here. Thoughts? `:)`

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the edit was major (not only formatting).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see why the source of the edit should really be of concern if you have reason enough to think that the edit is helpful. For me, the issue with major edits is mainly if they significantly change the question or answer, (even if good) in which case I'm inclined to be conservative on accepting them.  In that case maybe the provenance of the edit might come into play.

Comment: Great point, Alan. Thanks. `:)`

Comment: +1, afaik our standard for acceptable edits still is http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit