# "Official" capitalizations of words from the TeX world

Tags: discussion, editing

This is a detail, but in some instances I don't know right away how words from the world of TeX & friends are properly capitalized. While it's not necessary or "acceptable" to edit a post *only* to fix capitalization (unless it's near the top of the active questions anyways), capitalization often gets fixed along with other things (cf. [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/4012)). Hence, I thought it'd be good to have a reference here to come back to.

I'll start with one CW answer with categories of terms and preferably a source of the capitalization.

To add on the motivation behind this a bit: A part of the Stack Exchange model that I really like is its Wiki aspect. Not only do we help people solve their actual problems, but we also build up a database of knowledge for everybody to access. Decently understandable language and proper capitalization just underline the professional and high-quality impression that tex.sx has, which can really make it stand out from other web sites on the world wide webz.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Engines & Formats

- TeX
- pdfTeX ([source](http://tug.org/applications/pdftex/))
- XeTeX ([source](http://tug.org/xetex/))
- XeLaTeX ([source](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/xltxtra/xltxtra.pdf))
- LuaTeX ([source](http://www.luatex.org/))
- LaTeX ([source](http://www.latex-project.org/))

  - AMS-LaTeX (not usually a separate format) ([source](http://www.ams.org/amslatex))
- ConTeXt ([source](http://www.pragma-ade.com/))
- AMS-TeX ([source](http://www.ams.org/amstex))
- BibTeX ([source](http://www.bibtex.org/))

When one of these names is used as an instruction on a command line, it is almost always lowercase and in code markup, e.g., `tex foo.tex`, `latex bar.tex`, etc.

### Distributions & Bundles

- MacTeX ([source](http://www.tug.org/mactex/))
- MiKTeX ([source](http://www.miktex.org/))
- proTeXt ([source](http://www.tug.org/protext/))
- TeX Live [mind the gap!] ([source](http://www.tug.org/texlive/))

### Editors and Reference Managers

- AUCTeX (Emacs package) ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/))
- BibDesk ([source](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/))
- Emacs ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/))
- JabRef ([source](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/))
- LaTeXiT ([source](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php))
- LyX ([source](http://www.lyx.org/))
- TeXlipse (Eclipse plugin) ([source](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/))
- Texmaker ([source](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker))
- TeXnicCenter ([source](http://www.texniccenter.org))
- TeXShop ([source](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/))
- TeXstudio [formerly TexMakerX] ([source](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/))
- TeXworks ([source](http://code.google.com/p/texworks))

### Miscellaneous

- BaKoMa TeX / BaKoMa TeX Word ([source](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/))
- latexmk [capitalized like a regular noun, i.e. with a capital *L* at the beginning of a sentence] ([source](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/))

### Packages

Packages usually are all lowercase. On tex.sx, we tend to put them in code markup, e.g. `hyperref` (the source for this being `` `hyperref` ``).

Special cases are the KOMA-Script ([source](http://www.komascript.de/)) packages and classes, which have a proper name, used for referring to them as a whole, and the TikZ ([source](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)) part of the TikZ/`pgf` system for producing graphics, and the `SIunits` and `SIstyle` packages, which capitalise `SI` as it refers to the *Système international d'unités*, but that `siunitx` is written all lower-case ([source](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)). Also notice that `biblatex` is written all lower-case except at the start of a sentence: *i.e.* it behaves like a 'normal' package ([source](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

Comment: Could someone add a category about TeX, LaTeX etc. themselves, taking into consideration the distinction between format and compilation tool? I'm not sure I could find the right wording for that.

Comment: added section on engines & formats. hope i got most of them in the desired format; not sure what to use as a source for TeX itself (maybe it doesn't really need one?).

Comment: @AlanMunn -- i really did mean that ams-latex should be subsidiary to latex; it's not necessary -- and it's a great bother -- to load it as a format.  maybe it should just be listed as an "exception" under packages?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, sorry, I've put it back then.

Comment: @Joseph But would you write `Biblatex` at the beginning of a sentence? The page you’re linking to doesn’t put `biblatex` in code markup, so capitalizing it works, put code markup *and* capitalization isn’t a good idea imho.

Comment: @doncherry I tend to avoid writing package names at the start of sentences as a matter of course, to avoid this (applies to any package). So I'd favour with 'The `biblatex` package ...'. My point was that it's not anything like 'BibTeX'.

Comment: @JosephWright, so “The Biber/Biblatex system is invoked via the `biblatex` package”?