# Update official capitalization of LyX on tour page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tour

Under the [site tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) there is a list of information on questions that could be considered on-topic:

[image]

The spelling of LyX does not match the [official spelling](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2407/5764).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this: should now be fixed!