# Prompting the user to change "latex" to LaTeX

Tags: discussion, editing

While the issue of using "latex" instead of "LaTeX" is a small issue (not many authors have to be reminded of the fact), it would be nice to prompt the user and say something along the lines of, "Hey! You should use the proper capitalization of LaTeX instead of latex" and allow the user to either edit their question, or post it regardless.

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s worth the effort. Just edit it – returning (and minimally attentive) users will notice and hopefully adopt the habit.

Comment: We've created a reference to these kind of things: [“Official” capitalizations of words from the TeX world](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2407/5764) There also exists the ambiguity of referencing `latex` (the command-line executable) and LaTeX (the engine).

Answer (score 16):

I think this is a *really* bad idea. We strive to be an inclusive site, and enforcing such capitalizations is a great way to foster exactly the opposite view: "there are those of us who know the 'right' way and you are in the group that doesn't know the 'right' way."

As for editing, editing a post  just for such 'errors' is also inappropriate; if there are other worthwhile things to fix in a post, then fixing the capitalization of LaTeX is fine, but it should *not* be the main or only reason for editing a post.

See:

- [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/2693)

Comment: On the general point of fixing capitalisation, my understanding was that if the question/answer is 'active' (already on the front page, for example because it's new) then 'tidying up' was OK. Certainly that's how I read the linked question: am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Well, that answer in the linked question has relatively fewer votes.  I'm less concerned about people doing such edits than asking posters to do so, though.

Comment: OK, thanks for that