# What is a trivial edit

Tags: discussion, editing

When you try to edit a question, there is a request to not make trivial edits.  I wonder what counts as trivial?  Adding better tags?  Expanding an abbreviation in the question title?  Enabling syntax highlighting?

Comment: both of the examples you give are useful edits.  anything that assists in a more effective search is useful.  but if a poster misspells a few insignificant words (e.g., "teh" instead of "the") that won't affect a search, that's trivial.

Comment: Ok, nice, got it.  Basically, if it helps the future searcher or the current answerer, then it's worth it.

Comment: Well, don't forget that any edit you propose will require 3 reviewers to approve it. If two reviewers approve your edit, and then two reject it, then you will need a *fifth* editor to decide whether your edits will be approved or not. So every single edit you make could ask 5 other people to look at. That is a LOT of work for, perhaps, nothing. Think twice before you make an edit, and be certain that it is necessary to do it. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322660/should-i-simply-leave-very-low-quality-posts-unedited) from our sister site.

Comment: @Matsmath: I thought it needs two approvers only?

Comment: @Matsmath Not sure that case is about 'trivial' edits

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, all right, this might be site-dependent. In that case at TeX.SE two approve is needed, and with one reject, that is three editor's work.

Comment: @Matsmath: Ah, I did not know that this different on other sites. I am not active there

Comment: Some old, but still applicable discussion here: [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/340)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fundamentally edits should *improve* a post. However, minor typos - things that don't change the context of the post - should really be avoided.

I think the biggest reason behind this stems from the fact that an edited post becomes *active*, and active posts get bumped to the front page. In that case, chaning "teh" to "the" or removing "Thanks!" doesn't really help, since no new value has been added.

On the other hand, I've made minor edits to post if they've just been bumped as there is no real harm in doing that to an already-bumped post. I consider those just edits missed by the other person.

A broad discussion on (in-)acceptable edits is available from [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/5764).

[Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) references:

- [Why are trivial edits discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/168244)
- [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82893/168244)

Comment: It'd be nice if there was an option (not used by default) to not have an edit bump the post into active ones.

Comment: It might differ for users whose edits need approval, though, since those will get bumped again much later unless the edit is approved very quickly.

Comment: If someone referes to me with he/his while I'm a she-member, is it a trivial edit to correct it?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Not to you, but to everyone else... most likely.

Comment: Oh well, it doesn't matter, if I had realized it at once I would have corrected it immediately, when the post was still on the top of the list.