# Is it okay to edit other answers to a question I have also answered?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it (and isn't) acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit)

Say for instance, I have upvoted an answer but wrote another answer for more reference. But OP commented on the answer I upvoted that OP previously accepted as answer but unaccepted since OP thinks the answer did not work. So I wrote a comment that it actually works. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68860/increase-spacing-after-minipage/68865#68865).

Is it okay though to just edit the answer if the modification that will be done is substantial?

**Update** I think this post is a possible duplicate of this post: [Etiquette: when is it acceptable to edit anothers' answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/etiquette-when-is-it-acceptable-to-edit-anothers-answer?rq=1). I did not see it before writing this post although it did not appear as related question then.