# Link when referencing another answer

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, multiple-answers

When editing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/110394), I thought it would enhance readability/access when having

> Since this question comes up so often, I thought I'd try to supplement
> [ArTourter's correct answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63853/110394) with a more general comment.

instead of

> Since this question comes up so often, I thought I'd try to supplement
> ArTourter's correct answer with a more general comment.

---

I already did that quite a several times - is it considered bad practice for some reason? I think, it also gives the author of the referenced answer more of the credit. This is because an interested reader can easily follow the link and doesn't has to search for the respective answer. This might not hold true in this specific case, but imagine a question accumulating 20 answers (actually [the one referenced above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/110394) could still be answered by more people).

Comment: This answer could be considered: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/339/110394

Answer (score 3):

Turning my comment into an answer.

I wouldn't edit the post just for that. Especially if the other post is mentioned by way of a friendly nod rather than for an in-depth analysis or for a comparison. But if you are already editing the post for other (substantial) reasons I can't see any harm in adding a link, provided you can be sure you are inserting a link to the correct post (which is easy here, but may not always be possible if the reference is more vague).